# Symfony: Loading .env.test files

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I thought this PR fixed the issue I am having - but I have this patch and it's still not working as I expected - what am I missing or mis-understanding?

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/28533

I have created a .env.test with the following:

```
DATABASE_URL_TEST=mysql://apps:@localhost:3306/mydb_test
```

Then I dropped a doctrine.yaml inside the `config/packages/test` directory.

Symfony `v4.2.3`

However when I run this command from CLI:

```
APP_ENV=test bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test
```

I am getting an error:

> Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_URL_TEST".

Clearly the `.env.test` file is not being loaded - how do I get a specific environment configuration file to load - other than .env???

Comment: Was your application a Symfony 3.x application before ?

Comment: It may have been...I want to say yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If indeed your application was a Symfony 3.x application at some point, what I would guess is that, during the upgrade process, those two lines out of the UPGRADE procedure were missed:

> Then, upgrade the contents of your console script and your front
> controller:
>
> - bin/console:
>   https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/console/3.3/bin/console
> - public/index.php:
>   https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/3.3/public/index.php

Indeed, it seems like `bin/console` has been changed recently to reflect the adaptation done on the `DotEnv` component: https://github.com/symfony/recipes/commit/3e471cbc7d359b3ab245f3b0748d698e8d29692c#diff-2af50efd729ff8e61dcbd936cf2b114b

Mind that you'll also need https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/4.2/config/bootstrap.php

Comment: OK - it seems I may have used an early version of 4 - but was missing some updates and files (ie: bootstrap.php). Comparing my code base to a newer version of 4 I diff'ed/merged those changes and everything seems to work as I was hoping it would now :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. My issue was that my `phpunit.xml.dist` was pointing to the wrong bootstrap file:

Previously:

```
bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
```

Changed to:

```
bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
```